# Is it possible to invoke lambda from AWS RDS SQL Server on table row insertion?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I could see that in [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Lambda.html#AuroraMySQL.Integrating.NativeLambda) we can invoke lambda function from Aurora MySQL. But, I didn't see any documentation on RDS SQL Server. So, is it possible to invoke lambda function from AWS RDS SQL Server on table row insert or update?

Answer (score 1):

As of now, there is no available feature as you expected. One approach that may help you, is to use the AWS DMS to stream Change Data to Amazon Kinesis Data Streams. Refer to this [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/use-the-aws-database-migration-service-to-stream-change-data-to-amazon-kinesis-data-streams/) for the detail of implementation.

You can [consume the stream from kinesis with Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html) (or any other Kinesis-enabled app) afterward.

Comment: Thanks Teddy for response, here I am already using DMS for ongoing replication to RDS SQL Server. So, after every insertion into target table I want to invoke lambda/SNS with the jobid. I see option of lamnda_async for mysql but not seeing anything for SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think it possible using SNS. You need to add a permissions to invoke lambda to your database. See the documentations: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-rds.html

Answer (score 0):

This only works on RDS Aurora, not regular RDS.  AWS support confirmed that for me today....

Comment: Do you have any documentation for this? Did it work for you? Thanks